# writeArray binary file isn't displaying full array in readArray

Tags: java, file, file-io

I have two classes (writeArray and readArray) which should write an array of {10, 20, 30} and print it in a demo class but it only prints out 10, with no 20 or 30, and I don't understand if it isn't reading the whole array or if there's an issue with my demo code.

Here's the array class:

```
  import java.io.*;

  public class FileArray{
    public static void writeArray(){
        String fileName = "file.bin";
        int[] array = {10, 20, 30};

        try{
            FileOutputStream fileOs = new FileOutputStream(fileName);
            DataOutputStream os = new DataOutputStream(fileOs);

            for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
                os.writeInt(array[i]);

            os.close(); 
            fileOs.close();
        }

        catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        catch (IOException e){
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    public void readArray(){
        String fileName = "file.bin";
        int[] array1;

        try{
            FileInputStream fileIs = new FileInputStream(fileName);
            DataInputStream is = new DataInputStream(fileIs);

            System.out.println(is.readInt());

            is.close();
            fileIs.close();
        }

        catch (FileNotFoundException e){
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (IOException e){
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
  }
```

Here is the display class:

```
  public class FileArrayDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        FileArray write = new FileArray();
        write.writeArray();

        System.out.println("Done writing. Now reading.");

        FileArray read = new FileArray();
        read.readArray();

    }
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

You're only reading a single `int`. Instead, you should loop until you reach EOF:

```
while (true) {
    try {
        System.out.println(is.readInt());
    } catch (EOFException e) {
        // Reached the end of the file, break out the loop
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much, perfect!

Answer (score 0):

just add the for loop you used in your write method with your
System.out.println(is.readInt());